# In XPages Mobile App, can you clear viewScope variables between page changes?

Tags: xpages, mobile-controls

I'm working on an XPages Mobile app using mobile controls from Extension Library.

My hope page is a menu leading to 4 different mobilePages.

I get this this is 1 XPage and we're dealing with "Virtual Pages".  But is there a way to clear viewScope variables and document bindings as you go back and forth between virtual pages?

For instance.  In one of my pages I ask the user for some data.  3 Fields stored in viewScope Variables.  Using that I then have a button to Create a new document which gets bound to a panel and then I do things with it.

If the user hits "back" from the menu bar, to go to the Home screen and then goes back to the same page I want to clear everything and start all over.

setting resetContent= true doesn't do anything here.

My virtual page is a custom control and I tried to clear everything on beforePageLoad but that wiped it all during a manual refresh.

I tried hooking into the rendered property of the back button but that fired during a full page refresh.  Possibly I could live with partial refreshes but someone might still manually refresh it.

Any way to get this ability inside the single page app mobile context?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806358/xpages-mobile-controls-how-to-program-the-back-button

Answer (score 6):

See the following XSnippet on OpenNTF.org for your answer and a worked example - have fun! BTW: this is something we want to support on the Mobile App Page in an upcoming release - for now you can use the worked example I provide on XSnippets!

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=calling-server-side-jscode-during-mobile-page-transitions

Comment: thanks Tony!  That looks like that will do it.  Once I test for sure I'll mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using requestScope for the virtual page bindings? From your description, it sounds like this would be the correct scope to use.

Comment: Thanks Tommy.  I did try that and values were getting discarded too quickly.