# Server side javascript to replicate the moveto function in mobile applications

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm sure I am missing something obvious, but How do you provide the moveTo functionality like a djxmLineItem has in javascript in the case where I need to use a button to set fields in addition to switching mobile pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use server side to execute the mobile moveTo as these actons are handle by dojo client side code.

One option I've used in the past is to use a document "postSaveDocument" to call the moveTo.

e.g.

```
<xp:dominoDocument .....>
   <xp:this.postSaveDocument>
       <xe:moveTo ...>
       </xe:moveTo>
   </xp:this.postSaveDocument>
</xp:dominoDocument>
```

In my example I needed to maually add some data to a document with server side code ad faced the same issue, I found this to be a good solution as it won't run until the document has been saved, meaning all validation will run fine.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was actually going for, should have been more clear with my question

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the moveTo property and thereby set fields before moving to the desired XPage.

Have a look at the answer here: [XPages Mobile Controls - how to program the Back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806358/xpages-mobile-controls-how-to-program-the-back-button)